relationship in Laravel Blueprint?
I have a Receipts table that has several tables that normalise the actions on a receipt record.

Warehouse: Stores the locations
Status: Store the statuses of a Receipt
Comment: Stores all the comments relevant to a Receipt record. In the receipts table only an icon is displayed "comments_count" column
Attachment: Stores all the attachments relevant to a Receipt record.
Person: Stores information on who is assigned the task.

When a User changes the status of a Receipt record to Processing. It is assigned to a Person who also has the ability to add a Comment or Attachment.
My question is have i defined all the relationships correctly as unsure if the Processing relationships are correct in this example?
models:
  Receipt:
    warehouse_id: id foreign:warehouses
    location: string
    status_id: id foreign:statuses
    po_number: string
    arrival: datetime
    supplier: string nullable
    delivery: string nullable
    quantity: integer nullable
    consignment: string nullable
    comments_count: string default='fa-file 0'
    attachments_icon: string default='fa-upload'
    timestamps: true
    relationships:
      belongsTo: Warehouse, Status
      hasMany: Comment, Attachment
      hasOne: Processing

  Warehouse:
    name: string unique
    timestamps: true
    relationships:
      hasMany: Receipt

  Status:
    name: string unique
    color: string unique
    timestamps: true
    relationships:
      hasMany: Receipt

  Comment:
    receipt_id: id foreign:receipts onDelete=cascade
    comment: text
    timestamps: true
    relationships:
      belongsTo: Receipt

  Attachment:
    receipt_id: id foreign:receipts onDelete=cascade
    file_path: string
    file_type_icon: string
    timestamps: true
    relationships:
      belongsTo: Receipt

  Person:
    name: string
    email: string unique
    timestamps: true
    relationships:
      hasMany: Processing

  Processing:
    receipt_id: id foreign:receipts onDelete=cascade
    person_id: id foreign:persons
    timestamps: true
    relationships:
      belongsTo: Receipt, Person


why do you need a Processing table? can 1 Receipt be processed by many People or only by 1?

A receipt can only be processed by one person selected from the Person table

so why not have a nullable processor_id on the Receipt? you don't need a pivot table to map this relation
